# Summary for duration per month for each ID for TSQL / sql server 2016

Tags: t-sql, status, duration, summary, yearmonth

I have a table (##table) with an ID and the status for each day. I need a summary per month(!) how many days each ID was in which status. (##table_result). See below.

This was my approach. But it does not work. How can I summarize the days for each ID and per status for each month?

```
select item, Cur_Status, convert(varchar(7), s_date, 126) as YM_S_Date, lag(s_date) over(order by month(s_date) asc) as Start_date ,s_date , datediff (day, lag(s_date) over( order by month(s_date) asc), s_date) as duration from ##table order by item, Start_date
```

Data:

```
create table ##table  (item nvarchar(30), S_date date, Cur_Status nvarchar(30));

insert into ##table values
('A','2022/01/01','AA'),
('A','2022/01/02','AA'),
('A','2022/01/03','AA'),
('A','2022/01/04','BB'),
('A','2022/01/05','BB'),
('A','2022/01/06','BB'),
('A','2022/01/07','AA'),
('A','2022/01/08','AA'),
('A','2022/01/09','AA'),
('A','2022/01/10','AA'),
('A','2022/01/11','AA'),
('A','2022/01/12','AA'),
('A','2022/01/13','CC'),
('A','2022/01/14','CC'),
('A','2022/01/15','AA'),
('A','2022/01/16','DD'),
('A','2022/01/17','DD'),
('A','2022/01/18','DD'),
('A','2022/01/19','EE'),
('A','2022/01/20','AA'),
('A','2022/01/21','BB'),
('A','2022/01/22','FF'),
('A','2022/01/23','FF'),
('A','2022/01/24','FF'),
('A','2022/01/25','FF'),
('A','2022/01/26','AA'),
('A','2022/01/27','AA'),
('A','2022/01/28','AA'),
('A','2022/01/29','AA'),
('A','2022/01/30','AA'),
('A','2022/01/31','AA'),
('A','2022/02/01','AA'),
('A','2022/02/02','AA'),
('A','2022/02/03','AA'),
('A','2022/02/04','AA'),
('A','2022/02/05','AA'),
('A','2022/02/06','BB'),
('A','2022/02/07','AA'),
('A','2022/02/08','AA'),
('A','2022/02/09','AA'),
('A','2022/02/10','AA'),
('A','2022/02/11','AA'),
('A','2022/02/12','AA'),
('A','2022/02/13','CC'),
('A','2022/02/14','CC'),
('A','2022/02/15','AA'),
('A','2022/02/16','DD'),
('A','2022/02/17','DD'),
('A','2022/02/18','DD'),
('A','2022/02/19','EE'),
('A','2022/02/20','AA'),
('A','2022/02/21','BB'),
('A','2022/02/22','AA'),
('A','2022/02/23','AA'),
('A','2022/02/24','AA'),
('A','2022/02/25','FF'),
('A','2022/02/26','AA'),
('A','2022/02/27','AA'),
('A','2022/02/28','AA'),
('A','2022/03/01','AA'),
('A','2022/03/02','AA'),
('A','2022/03/03','BB'),
('A','2022/03/04','AA'),
('B','2022/01/01','AA'),
('B','2022/01/02','AA'),
('B','2022/01/03','AA'),
('B','2022/01/04','BB'),
('B','2022/01/05','BB'),
('B','2022/01/06','BB'),
('B','2022/01/07','AA'),
('B','2022/01/08','AA'),
('B','2022/01/09','AA'),
('B','2022/01/10','AA'),
('B','2022/01/11','AA'),
('B','2022/01/12','AA'),
('B','2022/01/13','AA'),
('B','2022/01/14','AA'),
('B','2022/01/15','AA'),
('B','2022/01/16','AA'),
('B','2022/01/17','AA'),
('B','2022/01/18','AA'),
('B','2022/01/19','AA'),
('B','2022/01/20','AA'),
('B','2022/01/21','AA'),
('B','2022/01/22','AA'),
('B','2022/01/23','AA'),
('B','2022/01/24','AA'),
('B','2022/01/25','AA'),
('B','2022/01/26','AA'),
('B','2022/01/27','AA'),
('B','2022/01/28','AA'),
('B','2022/01/29','AA'),
('B','2022/01/30','AA'),
('B','2022/01/31','AA'),
('B','2022/02/01','AA'),
('B','2022/02/02','AA'),
('B','2022/02/03','AA'),
('B','2022/02/04','FF'),
('B','2022/02/05','FF'),
('B','2022/02/06','FF'),
('B','2022/02/07','AA'),
('B','2022/02/08','AA'),
('B','2022/02/09','AA'),
('B','2022/02/10','AA'),
('B','2022/02/11','AA'),
('B','2022/02/12','AA'),
('B','2022/02/13','CC'),
('B','2022/02/14','CC'),
('B','2022/02/15','AA'),
('B','2022/02/16','DD'),
('B','2022/02/17','DD'),
('B','2022/02/18','DD'),
('B','2022/02/19','EE'),
('B','2022/02/20','AA'),
('B','2022/02/21','AA'),
('B','2022/02/22','AA'),
('B','2022/02/23','AA'),
('B','2022/02/24','AA'),
('B','2022/02/25','FF'),
('B','2022/02/26','AA'),
('B','2022/02/27','AA'),
('B','2022/02/28','AA'),
('B','2022/03/01','BB'),
('B','2022/03/02','AA'),
('B','2022/03/03','AA'),
('B','2022/03/04','AA'),
('B','2022/03/05','AA'),
('B','2022/03/06','AA'),
('B','2022/03/07','AA'),
('B','2022/03/08','AA'),
('B','2022/03/09','BB'),
('B','2022/03/10','BB'),
('B','2022/03/11','BB'),
('B','2022/03/12','BB'),
('B','2022/03/13','BB'),
('B','2022/03/14','AA'),
('B','2022/03/15','AA'),
('B','2022/03/16','AA'),
('B','2022/03/17','AA'),
('B','2022/03/18','AA'),
('B','2022/03/19','DD'),
('B','2022/03/20','DD'),
('B','2022/03/21','AA'),
('B','2022/03/22','AA'),
('B','2022/03/23','AA'),
('B','2022/03/24','AA'),
('B','2022/03/25','BB'),
('B','2022/03/26','AA'),
('B','2022/03/27','AA'),
('B','2022/03/28','BB'),
('B','2022/03/30','AA'),
('B','2022/03/31','BB'),
('B','2022/04/01','BB'),
('B','2022/04/02','BB'),
('B','2022/04/04','BB'),
('C','2022/04/04','BB'),
('C','2022/04/05','BB'),
('C','2022/04/06','BB'),
('C','2022/04/07','AA'),
('C','2022/04/08','AA'),
('C','2022/04/09','AA'),
('C','2022/04/10','AA'),
('C','2022/04/11','AA'),
('C','2022/04/12','AA'),
('C','2022/04/13','CC'),
('C','2022/04/14','CC'),
('E','2022/04/15','AA'),
('E','2022/04/16','DD'),
('E','2022/04/17','DD'),
('E','2022/04/18','DD'),
('E','2022/04/19','EE'),
('E','2022/04/20','AA'),
('E','2022/04/21','BB'),
('E','2022/04/22','FF'),
('E','2022/04/23','FF'),
('E','2022/04/24','FF'),
('E','2022/04/25','FF'),
('E','2022/04/26','AA'),
('E','2022/04/27','AA'),
('E','2022/04/28','AA'),
('E','2022/04/29','AA'),
('E','2022/04/30','FF'),
('E','2022/05/01','FF'),
('E','2022/05/01','FF')
;
select * from ##table order by item, S_date
```

Expected result:

```
create table ##table_Result  (item nvarchar(30), Start_date date, End_date date, Cur_Status nvarchar(30), Duration int);

insert into ##table_result values
('A','2022/01/01','2022/01/03','AA','3' ),
('A','2022/01/04','2022/01/06','BB','3' ),
('A','2022/01/07','2022/01/12','AA','4' ),
('A','2022/01/13','2022/01/14','CC','2' ),
('A','2022/01/15','2022/01/15','AA','2' ),
('A','2022/01/16','2022/01/18','DD','2' ),
('A','2022/01/19','2022/01/19','EE','1' ),
('A','2022/01/20','2022/01/20','AA','1' ),
('A','2022/01/21','2022/01/21','BB','1' ),
('A','2022/01/22','2022/01/25','FF','4' ),
('A','2022/01/26','2022/01/31','AA','6' ),
('A','2022/02/01','2022/02/05','AA','5' ),
('A','2022/02/06','2022/02/06','BB','5' ),
('A','2022/02/07','2022/02/12','AA','6' ),
('A','2022/02/13','2022/02/14','CC','2' ),
('A','2022/02/15','2022/02/15','AA','1' ),
('A','2022/02/16','2022/02/18','DD','3' ),
('A','2022/02/19','2022/02/19','EE','1' ),
('A','2022/02/20','2022/02/20','AA','1' ),
('A','2022/02/21','2022/02/21','BB','1' ),
('A','2022/02/22','2022/02/24','AA','1' ),
('A','2022/02/25','2022/02/25','FF','1' ),
('A','2022/02/26','2022/02/28','AA','3' ),
('A','2022/03/01','2022/03/02','AA','2' ),
('A','2022/03/03','2022/03/03','BB','2' ),
('A','2022/03/04','2022/03/04','AA','2' ),
('B','2022/01/01','2022/01/02','AA','2' ),
('B','2022/01/03','2022/01/03','AA','1' ),
('B','2022/01/04','2022/01/06','BB','2' ),
('B','2022/01/07','2022/01/31','AA','25'),
('B','2022/02/01','2022/01/03','AA','3')
```

Comment: This info might help you to make your post more readable. https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: You gave us almost 200 rows of data, which is *a lot* to proceed. We can't look at the data on a single screen, which makes it harder to grasp the logic you want. Please try trimming down your example to the minimal relevant dataset that properly describes your use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sure there is a more eloquent way to do this, but it seems like a gaps and island type of problem.  So here is a different way to go about it:

```
SELECT Item,MIN(S_Date) Start_Date, MAX(S_Date) End_Date, Cur_Status, DATEDIFF(day,MIN(S_Date), MAX(s_DATE)) + 1 Duration
FROM
(
    SELECT * ,SUM(CASE WHEN Cur_Status <> LG THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER(PARTITION BY Item,YR,MN ORDER BY s_Date) GRP
    FROM
    (
        select * ,MONTH(s_Date) MN, Year(s_Date) YR, LAG(Cur_Status,1) OVER(PARTITION BY Item ORDER BY S_Date) LG
        from #table
    ) X
) Y

GROUP BY Item,GRP,YR,MN,Cur_Status
ORDER BY Item,Start_Date
```

Comment: Thank you very much. There is a lot of data. I am currently testing and will inform.

Comment: Both versions work, but this one from JMabee is much more faster.

Comment: Great. If that is your solution please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Yikes, unless you're really super sure you need a global temporary table, you likely should not be using them at all.

Here's a good way to present your demo data and tables:

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (item NVARCHAR(30), S_date DATE, Cur_Status NVARCHAR(30));
INSERT INTO @table (item, S_date, Cur_Status) VALUES 
('A','2022/01/01','AA'), ('A','2022/01/02','AA'), ('A','2022/01/03','AA'), ('A','2022/01/04','BB'), ('A','2022/01/05','BB'), ('A','2022/01/06','BB'), ('A','2022/01/07','AA'), ('A','2022/01/08','AA'), ('A','2022/01/09','AA'), ('A','2022/01/10','AA'), 
('A','2022/01/11','AA'), ('A','2022/01/12','AA'), ('A','2022/01/13','CC'), ('A','2022/01/14','CC'), ('A','2022/01/15','AA'), ('A','2022/01/16','DD'), ('A','2022/01/17','DD'), ('A','2022/01/18','DD'), ('A','2022/01/19','EE'), ('A','2022/01/20','AA'), 
('A','2022/01/21','BB'), ('A','2022/01/22','FF'), ('A','2022/01/23','FF'), ('A','2022/01/24','FF'), ('A','2022/01/25','FF'), ('A','2022/01/26','AA'), ('A','2022/01/27','AA'), ('A','2022/01/28','AA'), ('A','2022/01/29','AA'), ('A','2022/01/30','AA'), 
('A','2022/01/31','AA'), ('A','2022/02/01','AA'), ('A','2022/02/02','AA'), ('A','2022/02/03','AA'), ('A','2022/02/04','AA'), ('A','2022/02/05','AA'), ('A','2022/02/06','BB'), ('A','2022/02/07','AA'), ('A','2022/02/08','AA'), ('A','2022/02/09','AA'), 
('A','2022/02/10','AA'), ('A','2022/02/11','AA'), ('A','2022/02/12','AA'), ('A','2022/02/13','CC'), ('A','2022/02/14','CC'), ('A','2022/02/15','AA'), ('A','2022/02/16','DD'), ('A','2022/02/17','DD'), ('A','2022/02/18','DD'), ('A','2022/02/19','EE'), 
('A','2022/02/20','AA'), ('A','2022/02/21','BB'), ('A','2022/02/22','AA'), ('A','2022/02/23','AA'), ('A','2022/02/24','AA'), ('A','2022/02/25','FF'), ('A','2022/02/26','AA'), ('A','2022/02/27','AA'), ('A','2022/02/28','AA'), ('A','2022/03/01','AA'), 
('A','2022/03/02','AA'), ('A','2022/03/03','BB'), ('A','2022/03/04','AA'), ('B','2022/01/01','AA'), ('B','2022/01/02','AA'), ('B','2022/01/03','AA'), ('B','2022/01/04','BB'), ('B','2022/01/05','BB'), ('B','2022/01/06','BB'), ('B','2022/01/07','AA'), 
('B','2022/01/08','AA'), ('B','2022/01/09','AA'), ('B','2022/01/10','AA'), ('B','2022/01/11','AA'), ('B','2022/01/12','AA'), ('B','2022/01/13','AA'), ('B','2022/01/14','AA'), ('B','2022/01/15','AA'), ('B','2022/01/16','AA'), ('B','2022/01/17','AA'), 
('B','2022/01/18','AA'), ('B','2022/01/19','AA'), ('B','2022/01/20','AA'), ('B','2022/01/21','AA'), ('B','2022/01/22','AA'), ('B','2022/01/23','AA'), ('B','2022/01/24','AA'), ('B','2022/01/25','AA'), ('B','2022/01/26','AA'), ('B','2022/01/27','AA'), 
('B','2022/01/28','AA'), ('B','2022/01/29','AA'), ('B','2022/01/30','AA'), ('B','2022/01/31','AA'), ('B','2022/02/01','AA'), ('B','2022/02/02','AA'), ('B','2022/02/03','AA'), ('B','2022/02/04','FF'), ('B','2022/02/05','FF'), ('B','2022/02/06','FF'), 
('B','2022/02/07','AA'), ('B','2022/02/08','AA'), ('B','2022/02/09','AA'), ('B','2022/02/10','AA'), ('B','2022/02/11','AA'), ('B','2022/02/12','AA'), ('B','2022/02/13','CC'), ('B','2022/02/14','CC'), ('B','2022/02/15','AA'), ('B','2022/02/16','DD'), 
('B','2022/02/17','DD'), ('B','2022/02/18','DD'), ('B','2022/02/19','EE'), ('B','2022/02/20','AA'), ('B','2022/02/21','AA'), ('B','2022/02/22','AA'), ('B','2022/02/23','AA'), ('B','2022/02/24','AA'), ('B','2022/02/25','FF'), ('B','2022/02/26','AA'), 
('B','2022/02/27','AA'), ('B','2022/02/28','AA'), ('B','2022/03/01','BB'), ('B','2022/03/02','AA'), ('B','2022/03/03','AA'), ('B','2022/03/04','AA'), ('B','2022/03/05','AA'), ('B','2022/03/06','AA'), ('B','2022/03/07','AA'), ('B','2022/03/08','AA'), 
('B','2022/03/09','BB'), ('B','2022/03/10','BB'), ('B','2022/03/11','BB'), ('B','2022/03/12','BB'), ('B','2022/03/13','BB'), ('B','2022/03/14','AA'), ('B','2022/03/15','AA'), ('B','2022/03/16','AA'), ('B','2022/03/17','AA'), ('B','2022/03/18','AA'), 
('B','2022/03/19','DD'), ('B','2022/03/20','DD'), ('B','2022/03/21','AA'), ('B','2022/03/22','AA'), ('B','2022/03/23','AA'), ('B','2022/03/24','AA'), ('B','2022/03/25','BB'), ('B','2022/03/26','AA'), ('B','2022/03/27','AA'), ('B','2022/03/28','BB'), 
('B','2022/03/30','AA'), ('B','2022/03/31','BB'), ('B','2022/04/01','BB'), ('B','2022/04/02','BB'), ('B','2022/04/04','BB'), ('C','2022/04/04','BB'), ('C','2022/04/05','BB'), ('C','2022/04/06','BB'), ('C','2022/04/07','AA'), ('C','2022/04/08','AA'), 
('C','2022/04/09','AA'), ('C','2022/04/10','AA'), ('C','2022/04/11','AA'), ('C','2022/04/12','AA'), ('C','2022/04/13','CC'), ('C','2022/04/14','CC'), ('E','2022/04/15','AA'), ('E','2022/04/16','DD'), ('E','2022/04/17','DD'), ('E','2022/04/18','DD'), 
('E','2022/04/19','EE'), ('E','2022/04/20','AA'), ('E','2022/04/21','BB'), ('E','2022/04/22','FF'), ('E','2022/04/23','FF'), ('E','2022/04/24','FF'), ('E','2022/04/25','FF'), ('E','2022/04/26','AA'), ('E','2022/04/27','AA'), ('E','2022/04/28','AA'), 
('E','2022/04/29','AA'), ('E','2022/04/30','FF'), ('E','2022/05/01','FF'), ('E','2022/05/01','FF') ;
```

Now on to the answer. This looks like an rCTE to me:

```
;WITH base AS (
SELECT item, S_date, Cur_Status, LAG(Cur_Status,1) OVER (PARTITION BY item ORDER BY S_date) AS prev_Status, CASE WHEN Cur_Status = LAG(Cur_Status,1) OVER (PARTITION BY item ORDER BY S_date) AND DATEPART(MONTH,S_date) = DATEPART(MONTH,LAG(S_date,1) OVER (PARTITION BY item ORDER BY S_date)) THEN 1 END AS Counter
  FROM @table
), rCTE AS (
SELECT item, S_date, S_Date AS StartDate, Cur_Status, 1 AS Counter, S_date AS StopDate
  FROM base
 WHERE Counter IS NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT a.item, r.S_date, a.StartDate, a.Cur_Status, a.Counter + r.Counter, r.S_date AS StopDate
  FROM rCTE a
    INNER JOIN base r
      ON a.item = r.item
      AND a.Cur_Status = r.Cur_Status
      AND a.S_date = DATEADD(DAY,-1,r.S_date)
      AND r.Counter IS NOT NULL
)

SELECT item, rCTE.StartDate AS Start_date, MAX(rCTE.StopDate) AS End_Date, rCTE.Cur_Status, MAX(Counter) AS Duration
  FROM rCTE
 GROUP BY item, rCTE.StartDate, rCTE.Cur_Status
 ORDER BY item, End_Date
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Basically what we're doing here is iterating over all the rows to make groups where they don't naturally exist.

It looks like your expected data is off too, I found this line:

```
item    Start_date  End_date    Cur_Status  Duration
----------------------------------------------------
A       2022-01-07  2022-01-12  AA          4
```

Should that not be 6?

Here's some of the example out put:

```
item    Start_date  End_Date    Cur_Status  Duration
----------------------------------------------------
A       2022-01-01  2022-01-03  AA          3
A       2022-01-04  2022-01-06  BB          3
A       2022-01-07  2022-01-12  AA          6
A       2022-01-13  2022-01-14  CC          2
A       2022-01-15  2022-01-15  AA          1
A       2022-01-16  2022-01-18  DD          3
A       2022-01-19  2022-01-19  EE          1
A       2022-01-20  2022-01-20  AA          1
```

Edit:

I modified the query to take into account the end of month.
The case <strike>statement</strike> expression handing the NULLABLE counter is now:

```
CASE WHEN Cur_Status = LAG(Cur_Status,1) OVER (PARTITION BY item ORDER BY S_date) AND DATEPART(MONTH,S_date) = DATEPART(MONTH,LAG(S_date,1) OVER (PARTITION BY item ORDER BY S_date)) THEN 1 END
```

and an additional predicate was applied in the rCTE:

```
      AND r.Counter IS NOT NULL
```

Example results are now:

```
item    Start_date  End_Date    Cur_Status  Duration
----------------------------------------------------
A       2022-01-20  2022-01-20  AA          1
A       2022-01-21  2022-01-21  BB          1
A       2022-01-22  2022-01-25  FF          4
**A     2022-01-26  2022-01-31  AA          6**
**A     2022-02-01  2022-02-05  AA          5**
A       2022-02-06  2022-02-06  BB          1
```

Comment: Thank you very much. There is a lot of data. I am currently testing and will inform.

Answer (score 0):

First of all thanks for your reply. Yes, you're right, it has to be 6.
I've try it but the issue is that I need the duration for every month. That means that if a period (start-end) goes beyond the month, the duration (start-end) may only be determined up to the end of the month. The rest from the duration should be determined and add to the next month.

For example: A | 2022-01-26 | 2022-02-05 |AA

Result:

A | 2022-01-26 | 2022-01-31 | AA |  6

A | 2000-02-01 | 2022-02-05 | AA |  5